# Weierstrass gap points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am studying Weierstrass gap points.
I cannot understand the following:

> If $n_i$ is a gap then there is no $ z \in K (X)$ with pole only at P, and $\operatorname{ord}_{P} z = - n_{i}$.

I am thus assuming that $P$ is on an algebraic curve $X$ and is a non-singular point.

Let be P a point on a nonsingular curve X of genus g. Let $N_{r}=l(rP)$. Then we have $1=N_{0}\leq N_{1}\leq ... \leq N_{2g-1}=g$. So there are $g$ numbers between 0 and $2g$ such that there is no $z\in K(X)$. This affirmation that I canoot to show it.

I want to show the existence of such points.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Something is missing here.  The only poles allowed for this $z$ is at $P$, otherwise the result is false.

Comment: I edited the question. Thank you very much

Comment: Is this not the definition of Weierstrass gap? If not, what is your definition of Weierstrass gap?

Comment: Let be P a point on a nonsingular curve X of genus g. Let $N_{r}=l(rP)$. Then we have $1=N_{0}\leq N_{1}\leq ... \leq N_{2g-1}=g$. So there are g numbers between 0 and 2g such that there is no $z\in K(X)$. This affirmation that I canoot to show it.

Comment: @Marcelo "...such that there is no $z \in K(X)$" doesn't make sense. Such that there is no $z \in K(X)$ with what property? Presumably $r$ is a Weierstrass gap if there is no $z \in L(rP) \setminus L((r-1)P)$.